# How to Create Objects Using Constructor and Return Random Result Using Invoked Method?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, constructor, properties

I'm trying to code a constructor which creates customer objects named 'customer' in which for each instance of 'customer' object has the following properties:

- Name (string)
- Drinks (in the form of array of strings) i.e. ["Coffee", "Cola"]

Here's my code:

```
 function customer(name, drink){
      this.customername = name;
      this.customerdrink = drink;
 }
```

Another method called 'Order' is supposed to return a random drink (in string format):

```
 function order(){
           return.this.name + ": " + this.drink;
      }
```

Then I'm going to create a 'customer' object instance with the properties:

- Name: "Julie"
- Drinks: ["Coffee", "Cola"]

  `var customer1 = {
        name: "Julie",
        drink: ["Coffee", "Cola"]
        }`

I will then invoke the 'Order' method to return one of the following random solutions:

Julie: "Cola"

Julie: "Coffee"

How do I get it to return the type of drink randomly?

EDIT:

Should I write my new customer instance like this instead?

```
 var customer1 = {
    name: "Julie",
    drink: ["Coffee", "Cola"],

    order: function(){
    return.this.name + ": " + this.drink;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that each customer can have an unlimited number of drinks they can order, and you want a random order of one drink for that customer each time you call the `order()` method then you just just need to pick a random drink for the customers `drinks` property?

```js
var Customer = function(name, drinks) {
  this.drinks = drinks;
  this.name   = name;
  this.order  = function () {
    var rand  = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.drinks.length);
    console.log('ordering a '+this.drinks[rand]);
    return this.drinks[rand];
  }
}

var bob = new Customer('bob', ['Coke', 'Pepsi']);

bob.order();
```